# Nodejs app deployment

Tags: node.js, развертывание

Возможно ли развернуть `node` приложение на сервере не используя `apache` или `Nginx` веб-сервера?

Comment: Для разворачивания приложения на сервере нужна только бесплатная операционная система типа Linux.

Comment: @ЮрийПирогов во всех мануалах, которые были мною найдены, пишут, что прилоджение запускается на локальном айпишнике, и нужно сделать прокси реверс с внешнего на внутренний. Для этого собственно и используются другие веб-сервера. Буду очень признателен за схематическое описание процесса, без дополнительных прослоек.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да. Это возможно. Вот кусок кода (взят [здесь](https://nodejs.org/api/synopsis.html#synopsis_example))

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = ''; // пропишите сюда адрес своего сервера 
const port = 3000;   // пропишите сюда желаемый порт (см. примечания после кода)

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Для того, что бы запустить сервер на порту < 1024 процесс должен иметь привелегии **root** (быть запущенным от root). А это создает дыру в безопасности системы. Именно поэтому рекомендуется использовать прокси (apache/nginx).

Answer (score 3):

Apache - это вообще из другой оперы, и если у вас приложение Node - забудьте про него. Устанавливаете Node самым обычным способом (на Ubuntu там две строчки для установки желаемой версии), устанавливаете базу (какая там у вас используется), тупо копируете туда приложение и запускаете его магической командой `nodejs server.js`.

И да, к имени домена или IP-шнику после этого придётся приписывать порт, который слушает ваше приложение (3000, допустим). И нужно всего-то перенаправить порт 80 - на этот 3000. Для этого обычно и используют Nginx. Но его можно и перенаправить просто командой в терминале: `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000`.

Все дела.

Comment: apache и nginx - это из одной оперы

Comment: reverse proxy можно настроить как на apache, так и на nginx.

Comment: затем же, за чем и nginx.

Comment: я лишь добавил, что apache - это из той же оперы, что и nginx.

Comment: Благодарю очень, ребята, внесли ясность)

Comment: да. но речь про apache и nginx.

Comment: @ЮрийПирогов, я Вас верно понял, изначально ноду стартовать на локалхост? Потому что с внешним айпишником сервер валит ошибку ` listen EADDRNOTAVAIL`

Comment: @ЮрийПирогов, вы совершенно правы, процесс я понимаю не очень, потом-то и обращаюсь к умам стака) Я имею ввиду, что прописывать явно в `server.listen(port, hostname,` хост при запуске уже на сервере? Адрес сервера, по которому к нему обращается внешний мир? Если так - то валится ошибка, что адрес not valid, хотя сам себя пингует нормально.

Comment: Ничего вообще не надо менять в приложении - какое было дома, такое и остаётся. Для него и База данных, если она тут же (а не где-то на облаке), так и останется по адресу `mongodb://localhost:27017/data` (ну, если она).

Comment: Теперь намного яснее, вроде

Comment: @Baga А! до меня дошло, в каком смысле localhost вас сбивал с толку. Если решить делать подобное же перенаправление через Nginx, то там перенаправление будет `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;` Ну вот как подключение к Базе данных, которая - тоже на localhost. Это они все - приложение, Nginx, База данных - ДРУГ ДЛЯ ДРУЖКИ потому что находятся на localhost (127.0.0.1). Ну это так, "остроумие на лестнице". В любом случае, в самом приложении тоже ничего не надо менять.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59618/discussion-between-baga-and--).